# Thread snapshot using CreateToolhelp32Snapshot is empty

Tags: c, debugging, msdn

I'm trying to get a snapshot of a process's thread. However, it's either returning an empty snapshot or thread_entry is not being populated. No matter what I seem to do my value th32OwnerProcessID is always 0. Any idea as to why this might be happening?

```
stack<DWORD> enumerate_threads(){
THREADENTRY32 thread_entry;

HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD,proc_info_1.process_ID);
if(snapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
    thread_entry.dwSize = sizeof(thread_entry);
    bool success = Thread32First(snapshot,&thread_entry);
    while(success == true){
        msg("Got thread snapshot");
        if(thread_entry.th32OwnerProcessID == proc_info_1.process_ID){
            msg("Adding thread to list.");
            thread_list.push(thread_entry.th32ThreadID);
            success = Thread32Next(snapshot,&thread_entry);
        }
        CloseHandle(snapshot);
        return thread_list;
    }
} else {
    err("Could not obtain snapshot");
    return thread_list;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the snapshot of the local process or another process?

Comment: Can't see why it doesn't work.  Try using GetCurrentProcessId() to get the process id (which should be a DWORD)

Comment: Oops, informed you wrong. I don't know why I said it was the local process. It's of another process.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign `dwSize` field of `THREADENTRY32` structure to size of this structre **before** calling `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`.